# $x+ay=4, ax+9y=b$, Find the values of $a$ and $b$ for which the system has more than one set of solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've tried $2$ different methods that my teacher taught me to get it, but I keep getting the wrong answer. Can someone please show me the steps as to how to get the correct answer?

Comment: Do you know the concept of determinants?

Comment: We are given two straight lines that have multiple intersection points, so they must be the same line (and in fact have infinitely many intersection points). Thus, <insert [Adriano's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4188133/21813)>.

Answer (score 1):

$x+ay=4\Rightarrow x = 4-ay\Rightarrow a(4-ay)+9y=b\Rightarrow 4a-a^2y+9y=b\Rightarrow (9-a^2)y=b-4a$. From this you can see that in order to have more than $1$ set of solution, it must be true that: $9-a^2=0=b-4a$. This yields: $(a,b) = (\pm 3,\pm 12)$

Answer (score 0):

The system has more than one solution exactly when the two given equations are non-zero scalar multiples of each other. So we know that:
$$
\frac{a}{1} = \frac{9}{a} = \frac{b}{4}
$$

The first equation tells us that $a^2 = 9$ so that $a = \pm 3$. The second equation tells us that $b = 4a$. So our solutions are $(a, b) = (-3, -12)$ and $(a, b) = (3, 12)$.